# Laravel auto run middleware for everypage without add Route::group in route

Tags: laravel

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){

}
```

I have a middleware need to get user's point when everytime page load.

Is anyway to let this middleware run without add route group inside of route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your middleware in the app/Http/Kernel.php

If you add it to the property `protected $middleware` it will run for every request.

Instead added to the proterty `protected $middlewareGroups` it will run only for web or api requests.

The code in Kernel.php is commented and pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

In your `App\Http\Kernel.php` file, add your middleware in `$middleware` array as:

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\AppAfterMiddleware::class,
];
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#global-middleware)